# Servir arquivo .js customizado em rota Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, route

Tenho uma página especifica "home" para usuário autenticado que é servida por um `router` contudo esta autenticação é feita via `cookie` se houver este `cookie` de "sessão" (criado após o login do usuário e definido seu path para o root) todo pedido diferente de "home" é redirecionado para ela (home).

Más preciso servir um arquivo `javascript` customizado que irá receber um tokem para ser usado por **socket.io** e também irá mostrar (incorporar) informações básicas do usuário e não posso faze-lo `inline` por questões de um "CSP" restritivo.

Como poderia conciliar isto?

**index.js**

```
// get routes
var GetRoutes = require('./routes/GetRoutes');
app.use('/', GetRoutes);

/**
 * Store sockets auth [in memory]
 */
var memory_auth = {};

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    // pre-store
    memory_auth[socket.id] = false;
    //
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        // flush socket from "memory_auth"
        try{
            delete memory_auth[socket.id];
        }catch(ex){}
    });
    //
    socket.on('authenticate', function(payload){
        //
        try{
            jwt.verify(payload, process.env.TOKEN_LOGGED, function(error, data){
                if ( !error ) {
                    /**
                     * check "socket.auth" ever "socket requests in home page"
                     */
                    memory_auth[socket.id] = true;
                    // add socket to user id room [to connect all user connections]
                    socket.join(data.id);
                }
            });
        }catch(ex){
            console.log('Authentication token failed!');
        }
        //
        setTimeout(function(){
            if ( !memory_auth[socket.id] ) {
                socket.disconnect('unauthorized');
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

**GetRoutes.js**

```
// middleware that is specific to this router
router.use((req, res, next)=> {
    var auth_cookie = req.signedCookies['_SCD_'];
    if ( auth_cookie && req.path !== '/home' ) {
        let user = users.getSession(auth_cookie); // function to getSession
        if ( user ) {
            res.redirect('/home');
            res.end();
        } else {
            next();
        }
    } else {
        next();
    }
});

router.get('/home', (req, res, next)=> {
    var auth_cookie = req.signedCookies['_SCD_'];
    if ( auth_cookie ) {
        let user = users.getSession(auth_cookie); // function to getSession
        if ( user ) {
            let file = getFile('home'); // function to get "home.html" file
            res.send(file);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});

router.get('/home/customJavaScript.js', (req, res, next) => {
    //
    var auth_cookie = req.signedCookies['_SCD_'];
    if ( auth_cookie ) {
        let user = users.getSession(auth_cookie); // function to getSession
        if ( user ) {
            // generate auth_token
            let auth_token = jwt.sign({
                data: {
                   id: user.id
                }
            }, process.env.TOKEN_LOGGED, { issuer: 'localhost:3000', noTimestamp: true, expiresIn: 5 });
            //
            var model = getFile('homeCustomJavaScript'); // function to get "custom.js" file
            model = model.replace(/{{+[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=+[a-zA-Z0-9=:.\/@#&-]+}}/gi, function(wholeMatch){
                if ( wholeMatch ) {
                    wholeMatch = wholeMatch.replace(/{{/g, '').replace(/}}/g, '');
                    var index = wholeMatch.split('=');
                    //
                    switch(index[0]){
                        case 'basic_nf':
                            let alias = (user.alias !== '') ? user.alias : 'Anonymous';
                            let user_nf = {
                                id: user.id,
                                alias: alias,
                                avatar: user.avatar,
                                mail: user.mail
                            };
                            return JSON.stringify(user_nf, null, 4);
                        break;
                        case 'auth_token':
                            return auth_token;
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    return '';
                }
            });
            res.type('application/javascript')
            .send(model)
            .end();
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

**home.html**

```
<body>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./home/customJavaScript.js"></script>
</body>
```

**customJavaScript.js**

```
 'use strict';
 var socket = io();
/**
 * send authentication to socket connections [ever]
 * this auto add authenticated socket to user id room [to all user connections]
 */
socket.emit('authenticate', '{{auth_token=auth}}');     

var basic_user_nf = {{basic_nf=basic}};
```